# Unicode Text in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an input field on my html page where the user can enter Unicode text, for example i enter : ыва ыва ыва ыва ыва ыв

When the form is posted, i check the value posted and it is posted as : Ñ‹Ð²Ð° Ñ‹Ð²Ð° Ñ‹Ð²Ð° Ñ‹Ð²Ð°

The content type of the page is set as :Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

When i display the posted value on the webpage, it shows as Ñ‹Ð²Ð° Ñ‹Ð²Ð° Ñ‹Ð²Ð° Ñ‹Ð²Ð° instead of ыва ыва ыва ыва ыва ыв.

How can i fix this to display properly? Do i need to do convert the encoding ? I believe c# strings by default are utf8, and my html page charset is also set as utf-8 - so not sure what's going on.

**Update:**
Here's my ASP Page :

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="utf8.aspx.cs" Inherits="enterprise10._garbage.utf8"
    ValidateRequest="false" Theme="" EnableTheming="false" ResponseEncoding="utf-8" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">    
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="UserInputText" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="UserInputLabel" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    <br />

       <input type="submit" />

    <hr />

<b>    Sample Text displays correctly on the page : </b><br />
    ыва ыва ыва ыва ыва ыв  



    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            UserInputLabel.Text = UserInputText.Text;
}
```

**Screen Output (IE9) Before form post:**

[image]

**Screen Out after form post**

[image]

Comment: .NET strings are effectively "Unicode" by default, although the storage is actually UTF-16. When you write the data out though, it should obey whatever encoding you've set. Please post some code.

Comment: This really helped me when I had encoding problems: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: +1 @fredw yes i've read that particular post by Joel before, its a good read.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adjust the encoding of your application, in the `web.config` file set the desired encoding for requests and response (under `<system.web>`)

```
<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />
```

Comment: @BrunoLM i do have the encoding setup explicitly in the page, see my update.

Comment: Ok i found the problem, like BrunoLM said in my web.config there was an existing entry for globalization set to "windows-1252" . I removed that and it works fine now.

Comment: Is there a way to explicitly override the requestEncoding in the code behind, irrespective for the web.config entry ?

Comment: @ace you missed the `requestEncoding`, I guess the value is not being sent correctly to the server side. Try adding `RequestEncoding="utf-8"` on your page...

Comment: You can not have RequestEncoding on the ASPX page.

Comment: @ace I've never tried, but it might be possible to modify in the `global.asax` on the event `protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)` setting `Request.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;`. I am not sure though

Comment: I tried setting it in the code behind with :  Request.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8; but the web.config value of "windows-1252" seems to override it.