# What is google's character encoding?

Tags: asp.net, character-encoding

Apparently Google's encoding is UTF-8 as it's stated in it's html meta tag.
But when I open a search page for scharfes+s with ASP WebRequest.GetResponse(), it's full of unrecognized characters. Does someone know what's going on there?

For your convenience, code is pasted below

Asp Page

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <div runat="server" id="output"/>
</div>
</form>
```

Codebehind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

public partial class SearchEngineCaller : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpWebRequest queryPage = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.google.com/search?q=scharfes+s");
        queryPage.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)queryPage.GetResponse();

        Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
        output.InnerHtml = readStream.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

[image: Returned Result]

What encoding should I use?

Comment: Do you see the same problem when you open this page from the browser directly? https://www.google.com/search?q=scharfes+s

Comment: nope. It's all correct using my browser

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5861309/600135

Comment: What's the encoding of your ASPX? you may be receiving Google's data correctly (try debugging and looking at the string) but when displayed on your page it's wrong because you are missing an explicit UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Maybe you need to save the aspx file with utf-8 encoding, and add a meta-charset tag too: `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

Comment: @TimMedora: After your question, I explicitly added <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">. But, there is no difference in the output. In fact, I saved the decoded stream to a file. Even the editing software cannot read the square characters

Comment: Can you guys have a try? I want to know if there is something wrong with my computer

Comment: Just tried it. It doesn't work for me either (tried reading the string with a variety of encodings too). It doesn't appear to have anything to do with the page; the string is incorrect after reading it from the stream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set some HTTP headers for the `HttpWebRequest` object:

```
HttpWebRequest queryPage = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.google.com/search?q=scharfes+s");
queryPage.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
queryPage.Accept = "text/html";
queryPage.Headers["Accept-Charset"] = "utf-8";
queryPage.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0";
```

IMPORTANT: Setting the `Accept-Charset` is not enough, it's important to set the `User-Agent`, too (I copied the above user agent string from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Requests)). I tried this solution, and it works for me ([test code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hmlecz9qlibtt58/GoogleQuery.zip)).

Comment: I really want to know why are you helping people? What motivates you? I try to answer other people's questions by returning the favour, but I get fed up understanding other people's problems quite easily. And I have endless work to do. Helping other people is never my top priority. Am I being too selfish?

Comment: Good question :) My main motivation is that I love solving problems. SO is a good source of *real* programming problems, and most problems can be solved in a few minutes (sometimes seconds). Actually this is a problem sometimes: answering questions in SO can be really addictive :) Anyway, SO is also a good place to learn, to practice programming. Last but not least, I'm happy to help others :)

Comment: I see. I wish the best for you. You are my role model